# GM/JS/JQ - Input Change With No Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am currently in development of a greasemonkey script. Part of this script will need to detect the change of an input box that has no user interaction. For a while I was using several event triggers such as mousemove or keyup/down and comparing the old and new values and updating accordingly. For some reason this can fail in my scenario.

The scenario is a system where sections of the page are changed dynamically and an input box is changed automatically to reflect the current section accessed.

I have tried setInterval to try and detect change but I am sure these days there must be a better solution.

Here is an example of what I have been using which seems to work most of the time, but I really need a more reliable solution.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
    if(savedId !== $('.only_class_element').val()){
```

Is there any way besides a setInterval to detect a value change to an input box with no user interaction?

This of course is called upon dom ready

Comment: are you executing all this on DOM ready?

Comment: Of course, also GM executes on DOM ready

Comment: By seeing your code can I assume that you are writing $('#id') and not $('id').. ?

Comment: Yes this is merely an example, the actual id is a class of which the only one existing on the page.

Comment: You may want to edit that in the question.. that creates confusion..

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Any version of jquery that offers this feature would be helpful and used by me, however currently I am using 1.7.1. The main issue is detecting input change not changed by the user.

Comment: Are you in full control of all code that changes the values? ( i.e. are you writing all the code that affects the values your interested in)

Comment: I am not in full control of the code, in such case greasemonkey would not be my choice and the features implemented by my script would be features of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, for an `<input>`, or similar, you would use the `change` event.  EG:

```
$('.only_class_element').on ("change", function (zEvent) {
    // DO WHATEVER HERE.
} );
```

However, if the element is not actually an input-type, or if the element itself is added/deleted/recreated via AJAX, then you must use an interval (or Mutation Observers, but I don't recommend that).  BTW, an interval is vastly less intrusive/resource-intensive than unfiltered monitoring of `mousemove`!

In the destructive AJAX case, use [waitForKeyElements()](https://gist.github.com/2625891), like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Monitor Cheshire-cat element for changes
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements (".only_class_element", fireOnChangedValue);

function fireOnChangedValue (jNode) {
    var nodeVal     = $.trim (jNode.val () );
    var lastVal     = jNode.data ("lastVal")  ||  "";

    if (nodeVal != lastVal) {
       //  DO WHATEVER WITH nodeVal HERE.
    }

    jNode.data ("lastVal", lastVal);
    return true;
}
```